# Provide Access to view "Enabled APIs & Services" dashboard

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I am not able to find any way to grant access to view the "Enabled APIs & Services" dashboard page. My co-worker does not have access but I can't find any roles or documentation that suggest what access is needed to view this page.  See attached image of issue.[image]

This [article](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/control-api-access#granting_access) suggests Cloud Endpoints can be used, but when I go to Cloud Endpoints I just end up at a blank page (see below):

[image]

Comment: If you feel like my answer has solved your question you can always mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving your friend the role of `Quota Viewer` should be sufficient, although he won't be able to see the charts for traffick/errors/median latency, he will be able to view the enabled API's. If he needs to be able to view these charts as well you could grant him the role of `Project Viewer`.

You can find out more about the available roles and their permissions [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles)

This role probably includes more permissions than is strictly needed, so you could always create a [custom role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-custom-roles) and assign it to him so that he only has the permissions strictly needed.

Comment: Sorry for delay, we did ultimately need Project Viewer to be able to view the charts. Thanks for the help!